# iterating over a set and list simultaneously using single for loop, how does it work?

Tags: python-3.x, list, algorithm, for-loop, set

here is a piece of code, print(B) gives set([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) which i am unable to understand.

```
M=[2,2,0,5,3,5,7,4]
A=set(range(len(M)))
B=set(M[i] for i in A)
print(B)
```

Comment: `print(B)` should give `{0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}` and not `set([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`

Comment: The code converts `M` from a `list` to a `set`, which could be done with `B=set(M)`

Answer (score 1):

No iteration over a set and list is being done simultaneously, rather a set is being created with the len of a list `M`, later another set is created using the previous ones element as `indices` to the original list `M`:

```
M=[2,2,0,5,3,5,7,4]
print(len(M))  # prints 8 as the len of M

A=set(range(len(M)))
print(A)   # prints a unique set with the len(M) i.e. 8 > range 0-7, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

B=set(M[i] for i in A)
print(B)  # prints the unique set using elements of A as index in the M list, i.e. {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
```